# SQL Timeout Error

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, indexing

I am getting a sqlserver Timeout in my aspx page.
It comes when i click one of the link in the website.
Will indexing will help with this problem?
Thanks

Comment: A little more information is needed. What operations do you perform when link is clicked?

Comment: it brings some images from the database to a page

Comment: I don't think it's an index problem, maybe the images are too big, connection is too slow, what is the queried table's size ?

Comment: i am not saying that is an index problem i am asking wheather index will solve the timeout issue

Comment: If it's not a query that takes to long to processed due to it's complexity - as I suggested in my answer - index will not resolve the problem - you need to find what causes the timeout - then if it's a index related problem - an index my resolve it.

Comment: Can you show us the **SQL Query** that pulls back those images? Can you tell us what that table you're querying against looks like (fields, how many rows etc.)?? You need to give us a bit more information to work with here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your page brings some images from the database, and index will only help if the database engine is having to check the whole table to find those images.

Putting an index on whatever you search for could well help, but it could also be an issue related to SQL having to get the image off the disk into RAM and them sending it out across the network. Is it quicker if you store the images on the webserver and return the Filename back from the database?

Comment: so u mean i shld only save name of the image in database and image should be uploaded in webserver?

Comment: Even for storing image on webserver i have to take more space?

Comment: Storing images on the webserver means that you won't have to transfer as much data from the SQL box, and the SQL box won't have to put as much data into its RAM, the table listing the images can be small, and so on. It's not necessarily _better_, but it can end up being a useful mechanism if security allows.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an ADO Command object, try to increase the number of seconds to wait while attempting to execute a command. That's set up thru ADO **CommandTimeout**. The default is 30 seconds.

http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_commandtimeout.asp

Each connection also has a timeout property in ADO, called **ConnectionTimeout** The default is 15 seconds.

http://www.w3schools.com/ADO/prop_conn_connectiontimeout.asp

Try and see which one hangs.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a query gone too slow problem - yes, if it's from something else (and it certainly might be other issue - that index will not help).

(other problems - networking, deadlocks, ect...)